# Copy table from online sql server to local server with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **localhost MySQL server** (wamp), and I have an **online MySQL server**.
The thing is that I want to backup a table from the online server to my local server (copy data between existing tables).

I've tryed to use `mysqldump`, but I have no result

```
<?php
   exec("mysqldump --host=onlinehost --user=username --password=password dbname table \
   | mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password= dblocalname");
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand if you have two MySQL or one sql-server. Update the question (and the tags).

Comment: Removed confusing tag

Comment: Why are you trying to do this via PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna take backup from online to local mysql server, you must open a port and define a static ip from your local modem. (you can fixed your ip from ISP).

```
<?php
$DBUSER="USERNAME";
$DBPASSWD="PASS";
$DATABASE="DBNAME";
$filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y") . ".sql.gz";
$mime = "application/x-gzip";

header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";
passthru( $cmd );
echo ('Backup Complate !');
exit(0);
?>
```

2. way you can take dump of DB and down the dumped file. Example script above, create a dump and download it automatically from web browser:
3. way, you can use backup programs for online mysql to local db.
4. way you can create a windows service with crons for get backups from online database to local db.

Comment: Instead of that,create a stored procedure that you call to do this. Dont expose your database to sql injection. That is, if this is hardbakes into the code.

Comment: @clifton_h you right, a different solution, thank you :)